# Show fragment over other apps when calling intent filter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to show my fragment as bottom sheet when the user clicks "share" from another app then chooses mine like the screenshot below from YouTube and another app.
Any idea how to do it?
Also, does it comply with Google Play policies or not?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: that is actually an activity with dialog theme, in that dialog you can show the bottom sheet

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out 3 hours ago and successfully made it. But I still have another issue with the theme, my whole app becomes transparent.

Comment: just apply the theme for activities you desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using a transparent activity with BottomSheetBehavior.